# Is anyone using the .NET micro-framework with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, .net-micro-framework

Now that Visual Studio 2010 has been officially released has anyone used it for developing for the .NET micro-framework and if so do you have any tips to help a newbie to the micro-framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using it with the FEZ Domino, it has the same form factor as the arduino so it has stackable "shields" but your code is c# and you can use visual c# (free) to program with it.  the site that has the FEZ Domino (and several other nice microprocessors) is [TinyCLR.com - .NET Micro Framework Community](http://tinyclr.com/)

they have a decent forum with lots of very smart and helpful contributors, plus videos on everything from setting up the processors, installing visual c#, doing updates.  it really is Freaking-E-Z(easy) just like their motto.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

By the time being (End of August 2011) I am a happy coder using the .NET Micro Framework with the Netduino SDK. See [www.netduino.com](http://www.netduino.com) for more information.

It uses:

Microsoft Visual C# Express 2010
.NET Micro Framework SDK v4.1
Netduino SDK v4.1.0 (32-bit) or Netduino SDK v4.1.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

The .NET MF is not yet available for VS2010, there will be an update in the next weeks.